# Databound DropList second option will not populate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

In my application I have 2 drop lists that I populate with information from 2 related tables and a label to store an ID that relates to both.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedType" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsMedType"
DataTextField="MedType" DataValueField="MedType" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Medication Type</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMedType" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource2 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [num], [MedType] FROM [pharm_medication_Type]">   
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Label ID="lblMedType" runat="server" Visible="true"/>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedication" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsMedication"
DataTextField="MedName" DataValueField="MedName">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMedication" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource2 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [MedName] FROM [pharm_medications] WHERE ([num] = @num)">

<SelectParameters>    
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblMedType" Name="num" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

here in the code behind I populate the label in order to get the `id` of the related table

```
protected void ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strMedType = ddlMedType.SelectedValue;
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [num] from [pharm_medication_Type] where [MedType] = '" + strMedType + "'", conn1);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn1.Open();
        int Result1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
        lblMedType.Text = Result1.ToString();
        conn1.Dispose();
        cmd1.Dispose();
    }
```

but when I run the application all of the options work except for the second option. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am advising you to use `ddlMedType` directly into `<asp:ControlParameter>` and do not use separated label for getting id, just set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` of `ddlMedType` correctly and enough. Please change your code as following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedType" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsMedType"
DataTextField="MedType" DataValueField="num" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" value="0">Select Medication Type</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMedType" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource2 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [num], [MedType] FROM [pharm_medication_Type]">   
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedication" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsMedication"
DataTextField="MedName" DataValueField="MedName">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMedication" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource2 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [MedName] FROM [pharm_medications] WHERE ([num] = @num)">

<SelectParameters>    
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlMedType" Name="num" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And remove the code on code behind event as follow:

```
protected void ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

Hope this help you.